# How to create a custom navigation bar (WordPress)

Tags: css, wordpress, svg

I have a requirement to create a custom navigation bar to replace the existing on a WordPress site. I have decent at CSS but have never come across something like this.

I have found multiple ways to remove the existing navigation bar so that is not a problem but adding the svg with links that are relative to the svg is.

The navigation bar is supposed to look something like this
[navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oztjA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve]. What have you done so far?

Comment: Did you know there's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to [wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) you might find that your question works better there if you check out its [help centre](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn't know that existed. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can approach this from two different angles.

**1 - You don't want to/can't use PHP**

You can create a custom menu through Wordpress' admin panel.

Add specifics classes to buttons (by activating CSS class property field on menu's buttons using "screen options" panel : ont the right top corner of the page).

Then you sould need 2 classes :

- one class for the links on the first row (who/what/how)
- another class for the link on the second row (contact)

and adjust de CSS rules to display links as you want.

Finaly I would display the "cloud" svg as the background of the whole menu.

*The real problem is that wordpress will output all menu items as `li` in a `ul`, so maybe you should create 2 differents menu (one per row), and display the two menus in a dedicated container.*

---

**2 - You want/can/prefer to use PHP**

This alternative takes advantage of Wordpress' [Menu Walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) by creating a custom walker extending it

The idea is that by customizing this PHP class you can specify how you want wordpress to render you menu(s) by defining the HTML output.

Here is some links to help you do that :

https://gist.github.com/kosinix/5544535

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/wordpress-custom-walker-output-section-of-menu/

Once you custom menu output is OK, you just need to customize the generated HTML though CSS.

---

**Note:** the second approach can be an adventure if you're not comfortable enough with PHP